# Рекурсивное деление отрезка пополам

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия

Требуется реализовать рекурсивное деление отрезка пополам. Мой вариант алгоритма (псевдокод, для простоты, комментарии в `{}`):

```
proc divide(B, E) {B - начало отрезка, E - конец отрезка}
     M = (B + E) div 2 {M - очередная искомая середина}
     ata(M) {процедура добавления в массив}
     if M = 1 then exit
     divide(B, M) {рекурсивный поиск следующей середины отрезка, начало-середина}
     divide(M, E) {рекурсивный поиск следующей середины отрезка, середина-конец}
```

Процедура вызывается в теле программы следующим образом:

```
divide(X1,X2)
```

Процедура `ata(M)` просто делает добавление значения `M` в массив.

Процедура должна делить отрезок с начальными координатами по оси `X` равными `X1` и `X2` пополам, половинки ещё пополам и так далее, пока длина не будет равна `1`.
Задачка должна быть решена именно рекурсией.
Помогите разобраться с проблемой, потому как берутся только крайние половинки как мне показалось. Правильно ли реализована рекурсия?

Comment: "Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой, потому как берутся только крайние половинки как мне показалось" - может быть вам все таки показалось, и задача выводит верный результат?

Comment: Что у вас M? Длина отрезка или середина?

Comment: к сожалению нет, рекурсия не все отрезки охватывает

Comment: М - середина отрезка

Comment: @Denis, ага, условие if M=1 then exit тогда зачем?

Comment: @Утка условие выхода

Comment: если длина отрезка нечетная, то длина отрезка никогда не будет 1. или по условию гарантируется что длины отрезков всегда четные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом коде есть несколько проблем.

1. `if M = 1 then exit` - неверно, логичнее `if B + 1 == E` или `if B == E` я лично предпочитаю 1 вариант (см ниже).
2. E не должно входить в отрезок. Т.е. если отрезок [2,4] E должно быть равно 5. Иначе на отрезке [2,3] вы разделите на [2,2] и [2,3] и вечная рекурсия. Ну или +1 добавьте ко 2 ветке.
3. (На правах зануды) Не `(B + E) div 2` а `B + (E - B) div 2` - избежать переполнения числа.

Comment: по четвертому пункту - если вы ищите координаты всех центров, то при таком рекурсивном решении нужны обе половинки, либо нужно додумывать как считать сдвиги для второй половинки

Comment: да, именно всех центров

Comment: @Denis так любое число - центр самого себя... Если центры отрезка длины 2 - то любое чётное/нечётное. Задача странная поэтому так и написал. Что можно без запуска ответ сказать это подозрительно.

Comment: @pavel речь идёт о нечте подобном кривой Коха, где каждый отрезок делится пополам, потом ещё пополам и так далее с необходимой глубиной фрактального дерева

Comment: @pavel а как нерекурсивно реализовать подобное?

Comment: @Denis http://ideone.com/BSdAVx это то что вам нужно?

Comment: @pavel да!! Спасибо огромное!!!